# como hacer que estos botones tenga una separación similar

Tags: css, responsive, mediaqueries, design

tengo una botonera, en la que por css estoy separando, pero a la hora de plegar la pagina web se solapan los unos con los otros quedando muy feo, **¿como puedo hacer que mientras se reduzca la pagina se mantengan con una separacion similar?.**

[image: botones en vista PC]

[image: Botones cuando se pliegan]

[image: Botones responsive]

```
    /*----------MOBILE-------------*/
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .mobileFloatCenter {
    float: none !important;
  }
}

/*----------TABLET------------*/
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .tabletFloatRight {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .tabletFloatCenter {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .tabletFloatLeft {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/*----------PC------------*/
.pcDisplayMargin{
  /*display: flex !important;
  margin: 0.05% !important;*/
}

.pcDisplayInline{
  display: inline !important;
}

.marginButtonsFilters{
  margin: 20px !important;
}
```

Comment: Podrías añadir tu estructura HTML para analizar bien la estructura qué estás usando. Aún así, puedo recomendarte que utilices flexbox, es decir, la propiedad display flex para modelar. Puedes chequear de qué se trata aquí: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Comment: lo reviaser, he intetando poner el html, pero me dice que es mucho codigo, que ponga algo mas

Comment: Prueba darle al contenedor de los botones display: flex. Y después podés trabajar con otras propiedades como justify-content. Saludos.